# Create dict from list of strings

Tags: python, dictionary, data-conversion

Given a list of strings as follows...

```
environment_variables = ['PIP_INDEX_URL=http://pypi.example.com/simple', 'PATH=/etc/apt/sources.list', ...]
```

... what is the most straightforward way to generate a dict from it?

It should look like:

```
{"PIP_INDEX_URL": "http://pypi.example.com/simple", "PATH": "/etc/apt/sources.list", ...}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the split strings directly to the `dict()` constructor:

```
environment_variables = ['PIP_INDEX_URL=http://pypi.example.com/simple', 'PATH=/etc/apt/sources.list']

dict(s.split('=') for s in environment_variables)
```

Which will produce:

```
{
  'PIP_INDEX_URL': 'http://pypi.example.com/simple',
  'PATH': '/etc/apt/sources.list'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
d = {}
for envvar in environment_variables:
    key, value = envvar.split('=')
    d[key] = value
```

You could use Python 3.8's new "walrus" operator here, but I don't think it gets any easier to read.

```py
d = {v[0]: v[1] for envvar in environment_variables if (v := envvar.split('='))}
```

Comment: Thanks, Adam. Your first solution is exactly the one I came up with except I used `pair` instead of `envvar`. This works, but I imagined there must be an easier way.

Your second solution is pretty hard to read.

Thanks for your solutions!